# I'm having problem on auto refreshing a content in a web page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I'm creating a webpage that will automatically refresh a content to always get the latest data in the database. This is my code in Javascript.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#status").load('refresh.php');
},1000);
```

In my javascript, I'm automatically refreshing the #status with refresh.php every second.

But when I inspect the element of my webpage and click on the network. It is also requesting(spamming) the refresh.php every second which is I think a bad practice.

Can you help me how to fixed this? Or can you suggest better ajax code to auto refresh a content without requesting the php file too much?

Comment: What you do to change this depends on how time sensitive these updates are. You are correct that ajax requests every second will put considerable load on server. If you need real time updates use websockets, otherwise balance need for speed with what you think is right for server. For example you may decide that doing this every 10 minutes might suffice and simply change the interval delay accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a websocket for this, get the latest status as data from the server and then change only that section of the page using javascript

Answer (score 0):

This code will be request `refresh.php` later at `timeouts.min` every time when new (requested) value of `#status` is equal to current. If values are different, next timeout will be `timeouts.min` again.

```
var timeouts={
 min:1000, // min await timeout = 1s
 max:16000 // max await timeout = 16s
};
var currentTo = timeouts.min;

function setAutoRefresh( to ){
  setTimeout( function() {
    var current = $("#status").text();// or .html()
    $("#status").load('refresh.php', function() {
      // if we are load a new value
      if( current !== $("#status").text()) {
        currentTo = timeouts.min;
      // if loaded value are same to current
      } else {
        currentTo += timeouts.min; // or currentTo *= 2; for example
        if( currentTo > timeouts.max ){
          currentTo = timeouts.max;
        }
      }
      console.log('Next #status refresh after ' + currentTo + 'ms');
      // Set a new timeout
      setAutoRefresh( currentTo );
    });
  }, to);
}

// Set the first timeout
setAutoRefresh( timeouts.min );
```

Comment: this would also spam `resfresh.php` which i think the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: No! its spam only if requested value is diffrent then current. If value is same, this code make request more and more later after previous

Comment: `load()` is asynchronous and this code assumes it is not. You should also provide a proper explanation of what it does and how it solves OP's issues

Comment: `load() is asynchronous`
Thanx! Fixed.